# EvaluationMonitor into a Table

Tags: monitoring

Is it possible to use EvaluationMonitor into a Table?

For example into this code

```
Table[{x, Sin[4 x]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.5}]
```

I would like to see changing of x and Sin[4 x] by using EvaluationMonitor

Answer (score 3):

You can, but it happens so fast, that you do not see it.   You could slow it down a little by adding a Pause?

[image]

```
{{0., 0.}, {0.1, 0.389418}, {0.2, 0.717356},.... etc
```

Code

```
data = Monitor[Table[Pause[.5]; {x, Sin[4 x]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}], {x, Sin[4*x]}];
data
```

You can change the last entry of Monitor as you want.

`EvaluationMonitor` did not work. I suppose because help says it is only for  **for various numerical computation and plotting** and `Table` is not one of these.

See help on `Monitor` for more information.

> And can I save data from every step?

You could do

```
data = Reap@Monitor[Table[Pause[.2]; {x, Sin[4 x]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.1}], 
          Sow@{x + 99, 3/4*Sin[4*x]}];
```

When done the first part of the data will be what Table generated and the second part will be what Monitor generated

```
realData = First@data
```

gives

```
{{0., 0.}, {0.1, 0.389418}, {0.2, 0.717356}, {0.3, 0.932039}, {0.4, 
  0.999574},....
```

And

```
dataGeneratedByMonitor = Last@data
```

gives

```
{{{99 + x, 3/4 Sin[4 x]}, {99., 0.}, {99.1, 0.292064}, {99.2, 
   0.538017}, {99.3, 0.699029}, {99.4, 0.74968}, {99.5, 0.681973}...
```

Comment: And can I save data from every step?

Comment: @MamMam fyi, updated.

Comment: Dear @Nasser, could you help me with this question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/276990/finding-eigenvalues-numerically-and-matrix-wise ? Sorry, but I do not know how to contact you directly, so I am writing through this post.

Answer (score 0):

To see what is going on, you may introduce a Print statement:

```
 res= Table[Print[{x, Sin[4 x]}]; {x, Sin[4 x]}, {x, 0, 3, 0.5}]
```

[image]